# dynamic data for ng-model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
  <input type="text" ng-model="rootFolders">
</div>
```

JS

```
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.rootFolders = '5';
}
```

How do i dynamically add data in place of "5", i.e the rootFolders.
for example adding a count data or a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking at something like this?

```
function Main($scope) {
var folders =  ['FolderA','FolderB'];
  $scope.rootFolders = folders.length;
}
```

you can assign value form to the scope variable like any java script variable.

Comment: hello i tried implementing the above solution, it worked. that you for that, but another issue rose for me, please have a look at this issue. [follow this link please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961250/getting-default-data-in-ng-model-input)