# getting default data in ng-model input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="tripsheet.tripsheet_num" type="text"> 
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.getTotalTripsheets = function() 
 {
  return $scope.tripsheets.length;
 };
```

i want the above data(getTotalTripsheets) to to default input in the input tag, in the above code i am fetching the length from the database table and tried making it as the default data in the input field.

i tried somthing like this(below), it dos not work, how should i proceed with this?

```
$scope.tripsheet = function()
 {
  $scope.tripsheet_num = !$scope.getTotalTripsheets;
 };
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.you define getTotalTripsheets as a function then you use it as a property `!$scope.getTotalTripsheets` .Furthermore your code makes little sense.

Comment: '!$scope.getTotalTripsheets', this is something i tried, i am really not clear on this. i tried getting the 'getTotalTripsheets' data in the input using 'ng-value' but the presence of ng-model overrides it, how should i proceed getting the length of the database into the input tag by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a one-time/one-way bind to the length of an `Array`, use `ng-value` instead of `ng-model`:

```html
<input ng-value="tripsheets.length" type="text">
```

If you have a two-way binding that can be changed from the default:

```js
$scope.tripsheet = {
  tripsheet_num: $scope.tripsheets.length
};
```

```html
<input ng-model="tripsheet.tripsheet_num" type="text">
```

Example in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UM4lyGZSxB1mEcpy9CqJ?p=preview

Finally, it sounds like you may be doing a remote call to a database, so you could use the following strategy:

```js
$scope.tripsheet = {
  $resolved: false,
  tripsheet_num: null
};
```

When the remote call succeeds, set `$resolved` to `true` and also set the value of `tripsheet_num`.  In the HTML you could do something like this:

```html
<input ng-disabled="!tripsheet.$resolved" ng-model="tripsheet.tripsheet_num" type="text">
```

Resolve example on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q2Ua8KGqWr6HDphe92q0?p=preview

Comment: i require the ng-model, since i am passing the ng-model="tripsheet.tripsheet_num" to a mysql database.

Comment: no its not a one time, nor a static data, would like to get the length

Comment: @user3689593 I added an example of a two-way binding with the default set.

Answer (score 0):

you are making you input a model of tripsheet.tripsheet_num which means that on the $scope there is going to be a property called tripsheet.tripsheet_num (I think, not sure because of the . what it will actually do.)

However i do know that when you make the tripsheet num a function it overrides whatever it was before and you should lose the .tripshee_num property. Your structure should be more like this.

```
$scope.tripsheet = {}
$scope.tripsheet.tripsheet_num = "default value";
```

if tripsheet is an array then change the model on you input to be "tripsheetLength" and change code to this.

```
<input ng-model="tripsheetLength" type="text"> 
$scope.tripsheets = ['info1', 'info2']
$scope.tripsheetLength = $scope.tripsheets.length; // length here is 2
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the code does get the default value, but how do i get the length of the database in-stead of the "default value"

Comment: just set it to whatever you want. where is the length at?

Comment: tripsheets are like a oneline bill(reciept). the data is stored mysql. The below code fetches the length of the tripsheets. `$scope.getTotalTripsheets = function() 
 {
  return $scope.tripsheets.length;
 };`

Comment: that code does nothing you are simply creating a function and returning the length of a variable. you need to do some sort of ajax call to get the info from the server.

Comment: i use `{{getTotalTripsheets()}}` in paragraph tags to get data but using this in the default value area does not work.

Comment: you need to load the tripsheet from the database